# Subline text color in webpage code snippet

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

I wonder, is there a way to get subline text color scheme in my webpage code snippet? I try google-code-prettify but there isn't the right color scheme. I want Monokai scheme. I try to search something like that, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your snippet in ST2 and then export it to HTML using [ExportHtml](https://github.com/facelessuser/ExportHtml).

> This plugin allows the exporting of a document in ST2 to an HTML file
>   or to BBCode. It duplicates ST2's theme colors and font styles.

Comment: Where i need to put this plugin and how should look my view file <div>Here is code snippet fragment</div>

Comment: Install via `package control` and then follow the documentation.

Comment: I am beginner in programming and all these things. Can you explain how to install it.

Comment: I installed it. I will try to follow documentation now.

Comment: Great.  I think you can right-click the selected bit of code and then `export` -> `HTML`.